# Can't connect to wms/wfs server on QGIS

Tags: geoserver, qgis, wms

I have one workspace named "novo". In fact, when i create a new workspace everything works fine i can see on openlayers my layer from that workspace. The problem is when i try to connect to my wms server on QGis which seems to do nothing, no error or warning is raised.

[image: qgis adding wms layer]

i can call GetCapabilities request and i have all my layers queryable and everything seems to work fine.

on geoserver log i can find the following statements:

```
2016-04-20 11:38:38,380 INFO [org.geoserver.wms] - 
Request: getCapabilities
    UpdateSequence = null
    Namespace = novo
    Get = false
    RawKvp = {SERVICE=WMS, REQUEST=GetCapabilities}
    BaseUrl = http://10.194.32.192:80/geoserver/
    RequestCharset = null
    Version = 1.3.0
    Request = GetCapabilities

2016-04-20 11:39:17,998 DEBUG [org.geoserver.config.impl] - Could not locate service of type interface org.geoserver.wms.WMSInfo in workspace WorkspaceInfoImpl[novo], available services were [WCSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WCS], WFSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WFS], WMSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WMS], WPSInfoImpl[WPS], WCSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WCS], WFSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WFS], WMSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WMS], WFSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WFS], WMSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WMS], WCSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WCS], WFSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WFS], WMSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WMS]]
2016-04-20 11:39:17,999 DEBUG [org.geoserver.config.impl] - Could not locate service of type interface org.geoserver.wms.WMSInfo in workspace WorkspaceInfoImpl[novo], available services were [WCSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WCS], WFSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WFS], WMSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WMS], WPSInfoImpl[WPS], WCSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WCS], WFSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WFS], WMSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WMS], WFSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WFS], WMSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WMS], WCSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WCS], WFSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WFS], WMSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WMS]]
2016-04-20 11:39:17,999 DEBUG [org.geoserver.config.impl] - Could not locate service of type interface org.geoserver.wms.WMSInfo in workspace WorkspaceInfoImpl[novo], available services were [WCSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WCS], WFSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WFS], WMSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WMS], WPSInfoImpl[WPS], WCSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WCS], WFSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WFS], WMSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WMS], WFSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WFS], WMSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WMS], WCSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WCS], WFSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WFS], WMSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WMS]]
2016-04-20 11:39:17,999 DEBUG [org.geoserver.config.impl] - Could not locate service of type interface org.geoserver.wms.WMSInfo in workspace WorkspaceInfoImpl[novo], available services were [WCSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WCS], WFSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WFS], WMSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WMS], WPSInfoImpl[WPS], WCSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WCS], WFSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WFS], WMSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WMS], WFSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WFS], WMSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WMS], WCSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WCS], WFSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WFS], WMSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WMS]]
2016-04-20 11:39:17,999 DEBUG [org.geoserver.config.impl] - Could not locate service of type interface org.geoserver.wms.WMSInfo in workspace WorkspaceInfoImpl[novo], available services were [WCSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WCS], WFSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WFS], WMSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WMS], WPSInfoImpl[WPS], WCSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WCS], WFSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WFS], WMSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WMS], WFSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WFS], WMSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WMS], WCSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WCS], WFSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WFS], WMSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WMS]]
2016-04-20 11:39:17,999 DEBUG [org.geoserver.config.impl] - Could not locate service of type interface org.geoserver.wms.WMSInfo in workspace WorkspaceInfoImpl[novo], available services were [WCSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WCS], WFSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WFS], WMSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WMS], WPSInfoImpl[WPS], WCSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WCS], WFSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WFS], WMSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WMS], WFSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WFS], WMSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WMS], WCSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WCS], WFSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WFS], WMSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WMS]]
2016-04-20 11:39:17,999 DEBUG [org.geoserver.config.impl] - Could not locate service of type interface org.geoserver.wms.WMSInfo in workspace WorkspaceInfoImpl[novo], available services were [WCSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WCS], WFSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WFS], WMSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WMS], WPSInfoImpl[WPS], WCSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WCS], WFSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WFS], WMSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WMS], WFSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WFS], WMSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WMS], WCSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WCS], WFSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WFS], WMSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WMS]]
2016-04-20 11:39:17,999 DEBUG [org.geoserver.config.impl] - Could not locate service of type interface org.geoserver.wms.WMSInfo in workspace WorkspaceInfoImpl[novo], available services were [WCSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WCS], WFSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WFS], WMSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WMS], WPSInfoImpl[WPS], WCSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WCS], WFSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WFS], WMSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WMS], WFSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WFS], WMSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WMS], WCSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WCS], WFSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WFS], WMSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WMS]]
2016-04-20 11:39:17,999 DEBUG [org.geoserver.config.impl] - Could not locate service of type interface org.geoserver.wms.WMSInfo in workspace WorkspaceInfoImpl[novo], available services were [WCSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WCS], WFSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WFS], WMSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WMS], WPSInfoImpl[WPS], WCSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WCS], WFSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WFS], WMSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WMS], WFSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WFS], WMSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WMS], WCSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WCS], WFSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WFS], WMSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WMS]]
2016-04-20 11:39:17,999 DEBUG [org.geoserver.config.impl] - Could not locate service of type interface org.geoserver.wms.WMSInfo in workspace WorkspaceInfoImpl[novo], available services were [WCSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WCS], WFSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WFS], WMSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WMS], WPSInfoImpl[WPS], WCSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WCS], WFSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WFS], WMSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WMS], WFSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WFS], WMSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WMS], WCSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WCS], WFSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WFS], WMSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WMS]]
2016-04-20 11:39:18,005 DEBUG [org.geoserver.wms.capabilities] - Collecting summarized latlonbbox and common SRS...
2016-04-20 11:39:18,006 DEBUG [org.geoserver.wms.capabilities] - Summarized LatLonBBox is Env[0.0 : -1.0, 0.0 : -1.0]
2016-04-20 11:39:18,007 DEBUG [org.geoserver.config.impl] - Could not locate service of type interface org.geoserver.wms.WMSInfo in workspace WorkspaceInfoImpl[novo], available services were [WCSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WCS], WFSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WFS], WMSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WMS], WPSInfoImpl[WPS], WCSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WCS], WFSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WFS], WMSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WMS], WFSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WFS], WMSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WMS], WCSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WCS], WFSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WFS], WMSInfoImpl[My GeoServer WMS]]
```

This is "novo" workspace GetCapabilities:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<WMS_Capabilities version="1.3.0" updateSequence="913" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wms" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wms http://10.194.32.192/geoserver/schemas/wms/1.3.0/capabilities_1_3_0.xsd">
  <Service>
    <Name>WMS</Name>
    <Title>My GeoServer WMS</Title>
    <Abstract>This is a description of your Web Map Server.</Abstract>
    <KeywordList>
      <Keyword>WFS</Keyword>
      <Keyword>WMS</Keyword>
      <Keyword>GEOSERVER</Keyword>
    </KeywordList>
    <OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://geoserver.sourceforge.net/html/index.php"/>
    <ContactInformation>
      <ContactPersonPrimary>
        <ContactPerson/>
        <ContactOrganization/>
      </ContactPersonPrimary>
      <ContactPosition/>
      <ContactAddress>
        <AddressType/>
        <Address/>
        <City/>
        <StateOrProvince/>
        <PostCode/>
        <Country/>
      </ContactAddress>
      <ContactVoiceTelephone/>
      <ContactFacsimileTelephone/>
      <ContactElectronicMailAddress/>
    </ContactInformation>
    <Fees>NONE</Fees>
    <AccessConstraints>NONE</AccessConstraints>
  </Service>
  <Capability>
    <Request>
      <GetCapabilities>
        <Format>text/xml</Format>
        <DCPType>
          <HTTP>
            <Get>
              <OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://10.194.32.192/geoserver/novo/ows?SERVICE=WMS&amp;"/>
            </Get>
            <Post>
              <OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://10.194.32.192/geoserver/novo/ows?SERVICE=WMS&amp;"/>
            </Post>
          </HTTP>
        </DCPType>
      </GetCapabilities>
      <GetMap>
        <Format>image/png</Format>
        <Format>application/atom+xml</Format>
        <Format>application/pdf</Format>
        <Format>application/rss+xml</Format>
        <Format>application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml</Format>
        <Format>application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml;mode=networklink</Format>
        <Format>application/vnd.google-earth.kmz</Format>
        <Format>image/geotiff</Format>
        <Format>image/geotiff8</Format>
        <Format>image/gif</Format>
        <Format>image/jpeg</Format>
        <Format>image/png; mode=8bit</Format>
        <Format>image/svg+xml</Format>
        <Format>image/tiff</Format>
        <Format>image/tiff8</Format>
        <Format>text/html; subtype=openlayers</Format>
        <DCPType>
          <HTTP>
            <Get>
              <OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://10.194.32.192/geoserver/novo/ows?SERVICE=WMS&amp;"/>
            </Get>
          </HTTP>
        </DCPType>
      </GetMap>
      <GetFeatureInfo>
        <Format>text/plain</Format>
        <Format>application/vnd.ogc.gml</Format>
        <Format>text/xml</Format>
        <Format>application/vnd.ogc.gml/3.1.1</Format>
        <Format>text/xml; subtype=gml/3.1.1</Format>
        <Format>text/html</Format>
        <Format>application/json</Format>
        <DCPType>
          <HTTP>
            <Get>
              <OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://10.194.32.192/geoserver/novo/ows?SERVICE=WMS&amp;"/>
            </Get>
          </HTTP>
        </DCPType>
      </GetFeatureInfo>
    </Request>
    <Exception>
      <Format>XML</Format>
      <Format>INIMAGE</Format>
      <Format>BLANK</Format>
    </Exception>
    <Layer>
      <Title>My GeoServer WMS</Title>
      <Abstract>This is a description of your Web Map Server.</Abstract>
      <!--Limited list of EPSG projections:-->
      <CRS>EPSG:4326</CRS>
      <CRS>CRS:84</CRS>
      <EX_GeographicBoundingBox>
        <westBoundLongitude>-25.1745333333</westBoundLongitude>
        <eastBoundLongitude>-12.198333333</eastBoundLongitude>
        <southBoundLatitude>30.004965</southBoundLatitude>
        <northBoundLatitude>37.93</northBoundLatitude>
      </EX_GeographicBoundingBox>
      <BoundingBox CRS="CRS:84" minx="-25.1745333333" miny="30.004965" maxx="-12.198333333" maxy="37.93"/>
      <Layer queryable="1" opaque="0">
        <Name>ABC</Name>
        <Title>ABC</Title>
        <Abstract/>
        <KeywordList>
          <Keyword>ABC</Keyword>
          <Keyword>features</Keyword>
        </KeywordList>
        <CRS>EPSG:4326</CRS>
        <CRS>CRS:84</CRS>
        <EX_GeographicBoundingBox>
          <westBoundLongitude>-25.1745333333</westBoundLongitude>
          <eastBoundLongitude>-12.198333333</eastBoundLongitude>
          <southBoundLatitude>32.4790833333</southBoundLatitude>
          <northBoundLatitude>37.93</northBoundLatitude>
        </EX_GeographicBoundingBox>
        <BoundingBox CRS="CRS:84" minx="-25.1745333333" miny="32.4790833333" maxx="-12.198333333" maxy="37.93"/>
        <BoundingBox CRS="EPSG:4326" minx="32.4790833333" miny="-25.1745333333" maxx="37.93" maxy="-12.198333333"/>
        <Style>
          <Name>point</Name>
          <Title>Default Point</Title>
          <Abstract>A sample style that draws a point</Abstract>
          <LegendURL width="20" height="20">
            <Format>image/png</Format>
            <OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://10.194.32.192/geoserver/novo/ows?service=WMS&amp;request=GetLegendGraphic&amp;format=image%2Fpng&amp;width=20&amp;height=20&amp;layer=ABC"/>
          </LegendURL>
        </Style>
      </Layer>
      <Layer queryable="1" opaque="0">
        <Name>doc1</Name>
        <Title>doc1</Title>
        <Abstract/>
        <KeywordList>
          <Keyword>features</Keyword>
          <Keyword>doc1</Keyword>
        </KeywordList>
        <CRS>EPSG:4326</CRS>
        <CRS>CRS:84</CRS>
        <EX_GeographicBoundingBox>
          <westBoundLongitude>-16.0555</westBoundLongitude>
          <eastBoundLongitude>-15.85316667</eastBoundLongitude>
          <southBoundLatitude>30.004965</southBoundLatitude>
          <northBoundLatitude>30.164367</northBoundLatitude>
        </EX_GeographicBoundingBox>
        <BoundingBox CRS="CRS:84" minx="-16.0555" miny="30.004965" maxx="-15.85316667" maxy="30.164367"/>
        <BoundingBox CRS="EPSG:4326" minx="30.004965" miny="-16.0555" maxx="30.164367" maxy="-15.85316667"/>
        <Style>
          <Name>point</Name>
          <Title>Default Point</Title>
          <Abstract>A sample style that draws a point</Abstract>
          <LegendURL width="20" height="20">
            <Format>image/png</Format>
            <OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://10.194.32.192/geoserver/novo/ows?service=WMS&amp;request=GetLegendGraphic&amp;format=image%2Fpng&amp;width=20&amp;height=20&amp;layer=doc1"/>
          </LegendURL>
        </Style>
      </Layer>
    </Layer>
  </Capability>
</WMS_Capabilities>
```

What am i missing?
It is strange since that this problem seems to occur without any reason.

Comment: please edit the question to show what your getCapabilities looks like? Does it have the workspace name in it? have you set any security for that workspace?

Comment: also in future you will probably get more/better answers asking questions like this on https://gis.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @iant, security is all by default. what is more strange about this issue is that it worked fine a lot of time.. there was some misconfiguration that raise this problem and i don't know what or why this is happening. I edited my post as you suggest.

Comment: does http://10.194.32.192/geoserver/ows?SERVICE=WMS work?

Comment: only local but yes it works

Comment: does it work in qgis?

Comment: yes, but won't show "novo" workspace, only will layers from another workspace already created before all this happen.

Comment: either you have disabled/secured  "Novo" or broken it some how

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109796/discussion-between-mrmartin-and-iant).